# Python Turtle is not working...The python turtle graphics screen is buffering on my Mac

Tags: python, python-turtle

//After proper indentation,It is still not working..

This is my code:

```
import random
import turtle
colors = ["red", "yellow", "blue", "green", "orange","purple"]
Turtles = []
for i in range(0, 6):
    my_turtle = turtle.Turtle(shape="turtle")
    my_turtle.penup()
    my_turtle.color(colors[i])
    Turtles.append(my_turtle)

screen = turtle.Screen()
screen.setup(height=500, width=400)
user_input = screen.textinput(title="Make your bet",prompt="Which turtle is going to win the race?..")
print(user_input)
x = -230
y = 150
for i in range(len(colors)):
    Turtles[i].goto(x=x, y=y)
    y -= 50

game_start = False

if user_input:
    game_start = True

while game_start:
    for i in range(0, 6):
        random_num = random.randint(0, 10)
        Turtles[i].forward(random_num)
        if Turtles[i].xcor() >= 230.00:
            game_start = False
            if Turtles[i].color()[0] == user_input:
                print(f"The Turtle with color {user_input} Won..You Won")
            else:
                print(f'The Turtle with color {Turtles[i].color()[0]} Won..You lose')

            i = 6

screen.exitonclick()
```

This is the error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/hassanmuzaffar/Documents/VS CODE/Python/Day19.py", line 48, in <module>
    my_turtle = turtle.Turtle(shape="turtle")
  File "/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Library/Frameworks/Python3.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/turtle.py", line 3813, in __init__
    Turtle._screen = Screen()
  File "/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Library/Frameworks/Python3.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/turtle.py", line 3663, in Screen
    Turtle._screen = _Screen()
  File "/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Library/Frameworks/Python3.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/turtle.py", line 3691, in __init__
    TurtleScreen.__init__(self, _Screen._canvas)
  File "/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Library/Frameworks/Python3.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/turtle.py", line 996, in __init__
    self.clear()
  File "/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Library/Frameworks/Python3.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/turtle.py", line 1028, in clear
    self.onclick(None, btn)
  File "/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Library/Frameworks/Python3.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/turtle.py", line 1365, in onclick
    self._onscreenclick(fun, btn, add)
  File "/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Library/Frameworks/Python3.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/turtle.py", line 669, in _onscreenclick
    self.cv.unbind("<Button-%s>" % num)
  File "/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Library/Frameworks/Python3.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/turtle.py", line 422, in unbind
    self._canvas.unbind(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Library/Frameworks/Python3.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/tkinter/__init__.py", line 1397, in unbind
    self.tk.call('bind', self._w, sequence, '')
_tkinter.TclError: can't invoke "bind" command:  application has been destroyed
```

I am trying to run my code and the Python turtle screen is buffering..not working properly.This code is working properly on online replit compiler...But when I try to run on my Mac..it is showing the above error..

Comment: How do you expect us to help when you have not shared your code?

Comment: Check [\[SO\]: How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) or
**[\[SO\]: How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example (reprex (mcve))](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)**
for more asking related details. 
Also, [\[JonSkeet.CodeBlog\]: WRITING THE PERFECT QUESTION](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question) might be a good point to start.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Now I have shared my code...

Comment: All the code starting from `screen = turtle.Screen()` should not be inside the `for i in range(0, 6):` loop. You only need to do it once, not for every turtle that you're creating.

Comment: After proper indentation,It is still not working..giving the same error..

Answer (score 0):

I believe this logic is a problem:

```
for i in range(0, 6):
    if ...:
        i = 6
```

Setting `i = 6` does *nothing*.  Unlike a language like **C**, changing the value of the iteration variable has no effect on the loop logic.  It will do what it was going to do anyway.  What you want here is `break`.

Below is my rework of your code with this fix plus some style tweaks and code cleanups:

```
from random import randint
from turtle import Screen, Turtle

COLORS = ['red', 'yellow', 'blue', 'green', 'orange', 'purple']

turtles = []

screen = Screen()
screen.setup(height=500, width=400)

x = -230
y = 150

for color in COLORS:
    turtle = Turtle(shape='turtle')
    turtle.color(color)
    turtle.penup()

    turtle.goto(x, y)
    y -= 50

    turtles.append(turtle)

game_running = False

user_input = screen.textinput(title="Make your bet", prompt="Which turtle is going to win the race?..")

if user_input:
    game_running = True

while game_running:
    for turtle in turtles:
        random_num = randint(0, 10)
        turtle.forward(random_num)

        if turtle.xcor() >= 230:
            game_running = False

            print(f"The Turtle with color {turtle.pencolor()} won. ", end='')

            if turtle.pencolor() == user_input:
                print("You Won!")
            else:
                print("You Lost!")

            break

screen.exitonclick()
```